# Keras LSTM Dtype in MatMul not the same

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm

So, I'm coding a LSTM model to find the next number in a sequence. But when I fit the model I get this error,

```
TypeError: Input 'b' of 'MatMul' Op has type float32 that does not match type int64 of argument 'a'.
```

I don't understand this question because Ive checked and all of the data and labels are dtype int64.

Here is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, LSTM
import random
import numpy as np

def makeData(total, types=5):
    #PATTERNS:
    #1)going up by 1
    #2)going up by 2
    #3)muliply by 3
    #4)multiple by 2
    #5)square number
    NumPer = int(total/types)
    Labels = []
    Data = []
    print(NumPer)
    for type in range(types):
        for i in range(NumPer):
            preData = []
            if type == 0:
                x = random.random()*100
                x = round(x)
                preData.append(x)
                preData.append(x+1)
                preData.append(x+2)
                Labels.append([x+3])
            if type == 1:
                x = random.random()*100
                x = round(x)
                preData.append(x)
                preData.append(x+2)
                preData.append(x+4)
                Labels.append([x+6])
            if type == 2:
                x = random.random()*100
                x = round(x)
                preData.append(x)
                preData.append(x*3)
                preData.append(x*9)
                Labels.append([x*27])
            if type == 3:
                x = random.random()*100
                x = round(x)
                preData.append(x)
                preData.append(x*2)
                preData.append(x*4)
                Labels.append([x*8])
            if type == 4:
                x = random.random()*100
                x = round(x)
                preData.append(x)
                preData.append(x*x)
                preData.append((x*x)*(x*x))
                Labels.append([(x*x)*(x*x)*((x*x)*(x*x))])
        Data.append(preData)
    return np.array(Data), np.array(Labels)

x, y = makeData(5)

def MakeRNN():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(3, activation='tanh'))
    model.add(Dense(9, activation='relu'))
    model.add(LSTM(9, activation='tanh'))
    model.add(Dense(36, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))
    model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss="mse", metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
Model = MakeRNN()
print(x.shape)
x = x.reshape(-1,1,3)
print(y[0].dtype)
print(x.shape)
Model.fit(x,y, epochs=20)

print(Model.predict([[1,2,3]]))
```

I don't understand this, I would appreciate any help from you guys. I don't know too much in the field of keras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code worked for me. Just made some tweaks to the x, y from makeData to convert them to floats. Also, the argument passed to predict needs to be 3 dimensional (at present you have a 2d argument) and it needs to be a float. Also need to add return sequences = True at first LSTM because it still has another LSTM after it.
Also, your model is a little bit strange. Keras expects the inputs to a sequential model to be of form (batch_size, timesteps, input_dim). You have timesteps = 1 and hence no sequence really. But that is a separate thing about what you want to do. As for getting the code to run, above tweaks worked.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, LSTM
import random
import numpy as np

def makeData(total, types=5):
    #PATTERNS:
    #1)going up by 1
    #2)going up by 2
    #3)muliply by 3
    #4)multiple by 2
    #5)square number
    NumPer = int(total/types)
    Labels = []
    Data = []
    print(NumPer)
    for type in range(types):
        for i in range(NumPer):
            preData = []
            if type == 0:
                x = random.random()*100
                x = round(x)
                preData.append(x)
                preData.append(x+1)
                preData.append(x+2)
                Labels.append([x+3])
            if type == 1:
                x = random.random()*100
                x = round(x)
                preData.append(x)
                preData.append(x+2)
                preData.append(x+4)
                Labels.append([x+6])
            if type == 2:
                x = random.random()*100
                x = round(x)
                preData.append(x)
                preData.append(x*3)
                preData.append(x*9)
                Labels.append([x*27])
            if type == 3:
                x = random.random()*100
                x = round(x)
                preData.append(x)
                preData.append(x*2)
                preData.append(x*4)
                Labels.append([x*8])
            if type == 4:
                x = random.random()*100
                x = round(x)
                preData.append(x)
                preData.append(x*x)
                preData.append((x*x)*(x*x))
                Labels.append([(x*x)*(x*x)*((x*x)*(x*x))])
        Data.append(preData)
    return np.array(Data), np.array(Labels)

x, y = makeData(5)
x = x.astype(float)
y = y.astype(float)

def MakeRNN():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(3, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dense(9, activation='relu'))
    model.add(LSTM(9, activation='tanh'))
    model.add(Dense(36, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))
    model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss="mse", metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
Model = MakeRNN()
print(x.shape)
x = x.reshape(-1,1,3)
print(y[0].dtype)
print(x.shape)
Model.fit(x,y, epochs=20)

print(Model.predict(np.array([[[1.0,2.0,3.0]]])))
```